# Remove other peoples' Google accounts on my device?

Tags: google-account

My friend used my phone to check his email but forgot to clear his account on my device, now his mails and notification come to my device, how do I remove his Gmail account and remain with only my account on my device?

Answer (score 1):

Open settings, and go to "Accounts and sync", from there you can see currently logged in Google accounts, and you can sign-out from there.

Answer (score 0):

Open settings -> go to "Accounts and sync" -> go to "Google Account", open which account you want to remove and there is "Delete/Remove Account" option in the menu(More option), you can delete the account from there.